# How to include style sheets and js files inthe view of Orchard cms

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, orchardcms

How to include style sheets and js files inthe view of Orchard cms,
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a ResourceManifest.cs file in your Theme or Module.

   ```
   using Orchard.UI.Resources;
   namespace MyNameSpace {
       public class ResourceManifest : IResourceManifestProvider {

           public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder) {
               var manifest = builder.Add();
               manifest.DefineStyle("MyScriptName").SetUrl("~/Modules/MyModule/Scripts/scripts.js");
               manifest.DefineScript("MyStyleName").SetUrl("~/Themes/MyTheme/Styles/site.css");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

In your view, include the script and style like this:

```
    @{
        Style.Require("MyStyleName");
    }

    @using(Script.Foot()) {
        Script.Require("MyScriptName");
    }
```

You can also use Script.Head() to put the .js include in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: I created a `ResourceManifest.cs` inside the theme project and defined a script resource like you demonstrated. But I still get an error: 'script' named 'MenuScript' could not be found, I get this error inside the ResourceManager.cs file. Do you have to carry out any additional steps to ensure that the resource becomes available? I put a breakpoint inside the ResourceManifest.cs and it never gets hit. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You may also use `Script.Include` and `Style.Include` if you don't want to create a manifest but want to reference the files directly but still eliminating doubles.

The `404` here is very probably due to your failing to include a `web.config` file that allows the serving of the file. You can copy the one from one of the existing script directories.